# Sublime Text's syntax highlighting of regexes in python leaks into surrounding code

Tags: python, sublimetext2, color-scheme

I have a problem with sublime text which should be generally all editors. When I have a regular expression like this.

```
listRegex = re.findall(r'[*][[][[].*', testString)
```

All the text after the regular expression will be incorrectly highlighted, because of the `[[]`, specifically the `[` without a close bracket. While the intention of this regular expression is correct, the editor doesn't know this.

This is just an annoyance I don't know how to deal with. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Just put the closing braces in a comment at the end of the line. The line itself may not look good but at least it doesn't taint the rest of the code highlighting.

Comment: You'll need to modify the `Package/Python/Regular Expressions (Python).tmLanguage` file to fix this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it doesn't really answer your question, you could just use a different regex:

```
listRegex = re.findall(r'\*\[\[.*', testString)
```

Or you can prevent any regex highligting:

```
listRegex = re.findall(R'[*][[][[].*', testString)
```

---

#### Proper solution

Add the following to `.../Packages/Python/Regular Expressions (Python).tmLanguage` on line 266 (first and third blocks are context):

```
<key>name</key>
<string>constant.other.character-class.set.regexp</string>
<key>patterns</key>
<array>
```

```xml
    <dict>
        <key>match</key>
        <string>\[</string>
    </dict>
```

```
    <dict>
        <key>include</key>
        <string>#character-class</string>
    </dict>
```

Comment: By the way, thanks for the answer. And all other who tried to help :)

Comment: What does the change of `r` to `R` do? I quite don't understand the sentence above.

Comment: @Qwerty: Python doesn't care which you use. Sublime text will only syntax highlight regexes if the raw string uses a lowercase r. I don't know if this is by design or accidental

Comment: @Eric So we are actually exploiting a bug, haha, clever! :)

Answer (score 2):

That's a known bug of Sublime Text's Python Syntax Highlighter that only affects raw strings.

By the way in a regex you can match a special character in two ways:

1. Enclosing it in a square bracket: `[[]`
2. Escaping it with a backslash: `\[`

The second one is preferred, so you can change your code to:

```
listRegex = re.findall(r'\*\[\[.*', testString)
```